# Inject SoapClient into a class (Dependency Injection )

Tags: php, laravel, dependency-injection

I'm trying to Inject a SoapClient dependency into Foo class, I've made a provider container but I can't resolve the dependency.

This is the class I'm trying to Inject the dependency in.

```
   namespace App\Services
   Class Foo{

      public function __construct(   )
      {


          $this->SoapClient = resolve('MySoapClient');

      }

      public  function someMethod($data)
      {


          $req=$this->SoapClient->getSomething($params);
          return $req;
      }

  }
```

this is the service provider

```
namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Broadcast;
use \Illuminate\Foundation\Application;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{


    public function register()
    {


        $this->app->bind('MySoapClient', function ($app) {
        return new \SoapClient(env('wsdl'));
        });

     }

}
```

I just want to inject SoapClient into the Foo class. the above code is not working and I'm getting that( class MySoapClient doesn't exist )

Comment: Actually I don't have that class, this solution was provided to me by someone.
I'm totally open to any new idea to solve my issue

Comment: You're right, that bit of my comment wasn't right

Comment: yeah man, So any idea on fixing my issue here